# hiding element using JQuery failing

Tags: jquery

Would somebody be able to tell me what i am doing wrong in this simple hide element script using 
JQuery? When i click the button its meant to hide the text in the disclaimer tag. Thanks.

index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML">
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
<meta name="" content="">
<script src="script.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='jquery.js'></script>
</head>
<body>
<input type="button" id="hideButton" value="hide"/>

<div id="disclaimer">
<p>This is a disclaimer</p>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

script.js:

```
$('#hideButton').click(function() {

    $('#disclaimer').hide();

});
```

Comment: Check if you're getting errors, my guess is jQuery isn't referenced properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#hideButton').click(function() {

    $('#disclaimer').hide();

});
});
```

you should enclose it  in document ready
also reference `jquery.js` before `script.js`

Comment: Yes, you're binding the event before the element is in the DOM, so it's not attaching. You could also place the javascript inline AFTER the HTML.

Answer (score 1):

Wait until your dom loads and then load the script

demo : http://jsfiddle.net/epinapala/Pm2k6/3/

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML">
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
<meta name="" content="">
<script src="script.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='jquery.js'></script>
</head>
<body>
<input type="button" id="hideButton" value="hide"/>

<div id="disclaimer">
<p>This is a disclaimer</p>

</div>
    <script>
    $('#hideButton').click(function() {

    $('#disclaimer').hide("slow");

});
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Alternatively you can use

```
$(document).ready(function(){
//this will be executed after dom is loaded.
});
```

Comment: strange enough it doesn't seem to work when they are in the index.html and script.js files..

Comment: Yeah, You should probably keep <script src="script.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
 after disclaimer div. however, $(document).ready() should solve these problems

Answer (score -1):

Another way around

```
<div id="disclaimer" style="block">
<p>This is a disclaimer</p>

</div>



<script>
$('#hideButton').click(function() {

   $('#disclaimer').css('display','none');

});
 </script>
```

Comment: `$.hide()` does the same thing, don't see how this would solve the problem.

Comment: $.hide() is the same apart from the value of the display property is saved in jQuery's data cache. so i just suggested another way around not having to wait for dom to fully load.